Does the two dimension erasure code have a corresponding generation matrix?
Here is a example of X-code, which is a kind of vertical code.Each column represents a disk, each matrix represents a data block, and each pair of numbers represents which parity block this data block participates in.It is easy to observe that the parity blocks are generated in a staggered manner according to the shape of "X".
In traditional erasure code such as RS code, one data block is corresponding to one code symbol.However, in these two dimension erasure code, it seems that some data blocks are aggregated together to form one symbol. I have consulted some literature, most of which only use common bound theorems to analysis the performance, such as the Singleton bound. Thus, i am curious about whether the two dimension erasure code have a corresponding generation matrix. My mentor said he seems to have seen it before, but he forgot about it


why don't you give a link to the technical literature you are referring to, to make the question more precise. The reason is that your "combined" together statement is vague. define what exactly the figure means, what is d_i, and a number j vs a pair j,k in boxes.
